How to specify that case should be ignored within a string pattern?
One can use StringMatchQ to test whether a string matches a string pattern. One can use the IgnoreCase option of StringMatchQ to ignore case when comparing the string and the string pattern:
StringMatchQ["Apple", "Apple"]
StringMatchQ["Apple", "apple"]
StringMatchQ["Apple", "apple", IgnoreCase -> True]
(* `True *)
(* `False` *)
(* `True` *)

How can I include the directive to "ignore case" directly within the string pattern or StringExpression -- rather than using the IgnoreCase option? I have found the function CaseSensitive, which takes a string pattern as input and returns a case-sensitive string pattern:
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression["Apple"]]
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression["apple"]]
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression["apple"], IgnoreCase -> True]
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression[CaseSensitive["Apple"]]]
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression[CaseSensitive["apple"]]]
StringMatchQ["Apple", StringExpression[CaseSensitive["apple"]],
  IgnoreCase -> True]
(* `True` *)
(* `False` *)
(* `True` *)
(* `True` *)
(* `False` *)
(* `False` *)

Is there a way to somehow "negate" CaseSensitive so that the string pattern specifies string insensitivity?

Try: StringMatchQ["Apple", ("A" | "a") ~~ "pple"]

Here we have "apple and " sensitive and "pear" insensitive using CaseSensitive.
StringMatchQ["Apple and pear", CaseSensitive["Apple and "] ~~ "pEaR", 
 IgnoreCase -> True]

StringMatchQ["Apple and pear", CaseSensitive["apple and "] ~~ "pEaR", 
 IgnoreCase -> True]


True

False

Here we have the same sensitivity but instead of CaseSensitive we can use ins with rule in pattern. You have to use /. rule at the end of the pattern and option IgnoreCase -> True but you do not have to use CaseSensitive just the opposite ins.
rule = {x_String -> CaseSensitive[x], ins[x_String] -> Identity[x]};

StringMatchQ["Apple and pear", "Apple and " ~~ ins["pEaR"] /. rule, 
 IgnoreCase -> True]

StringMatchQ["Apple and pear", "apple and " ~~ ins["pEaR"] /. rule, 
 IgnoreCase -> True]


True

False

Or you can make your own function SMQ.
ins stands for "case-insensitive", use any other word you like instead of ins.
SMQ[s_, p_] := 
 StringMatchQ[s, 
  p /. {x_String -> CaseSensitive[x], ins[x_String] -> Identity[x]}, 
  IgnoreCase -> True]

SMQ["Apple and pear", "Apple and " ~~ ins["pEaR"]]
SMQ["Apple and pear", "apple and " ~~ ins["pEaR"]]


True

False


StringExpressions have many nice properties, but I generally prefer RegularExpressions. At some point, StringExpressions become unweildy, and sometimes I just can't get them to do what I want. So, with that in mind, here's what you could do:
StringMatchQ["Apple", RegularExpression["(?i)apple"]]
(* True *)

